# Python script is running in Pycharm but not via bat file

Tags: python, pandas, batch-file, error-handling

I have a python script that is running OK in PyCharm.
It's first line is 'import pandas'

I created a bat file that looks like this:
***"C:\Users\icohen1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" "C:\Users\MyName\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\LotsToTextFile.py"
pause***

When I run this bat file I get this error:
***import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'***

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported the Modul with pip?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the python environment you use in Pycharm is not `C:\Users\icohen1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`, but a virtual env Pycharm created for your project.

If you wish to run with the virtual env, go to Pycharm and find where the python.exe if virtual env is located, and modify your python path.

If you wish to run with `"C:\Users\icohen1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"`, you should install pandas for that global python.exe.
Usually this will install it.
in cmd shell

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Yes, I did the PIP install and it worked.